# GraalVM-built native image does not support Unsafe.staticFieldOffset() method

Tags: java, unsafe, graalvm-native-image

I have the following program in a file called `Test.java`:

```
import sun.misc.Unsafe;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Field unsafeField = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        unsafeField.setAccessible(true);
        Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe) unsafeField.get(null);
        long offset = unsafe.staticFieldOffset(unsafeField);
        System.out.println(offset);
    }
}
```

It just obtains an `Unsafe` instance and then calls its `staticFieldOffset()` method.

I compile it with `javac Test.java`, it outputs a bunch of warnings about the dangers of `Unsafe`.

Then I run the produced class file with `java Test` and get the following:

```
104
```

So it works.

Now, I build a native image with `native-image --no-server --no-fallback Test app`.

```
[app:11806]    classlist:   1,486.00 ms,  0.96 GB
[app:11806]        (cap):     481.32 ms,  0.96 GB
[app:11806]        setup:   1,628.06 ms,  0.96 GB
[app:11806]     (clinit):     201.38 ms,  1.70 GB
[app:11806]   (typeflow):   5,540.87 ms,  1.70 GB
[app:11806]    (objects):   4,523.67 ms,  1.70 GB
[app:11806]   (features):     251.65 ms,  1.70 GB
[app:11806]     analysis:  10,741.48 ms,  1.70 GB
[app:11806]     universe:     368.62 ms,  1.70 GB
[app:11806]      (parse):   1,327.10 ms,  1.70 GB
[app:11806]     (inline):   1,156.04 ms,  1.70 GB
[app:11806]    (compile):   8,106.76 ms,  2.33 GB
[app:11806]      compile:  10,998.36 ms,  2.33 GB
[app:11806]        image:     765.81 ms,  2.33 GB
[app:11806]        write:     137.50 ms,  2.33 GB
[app:11806]      [total]:  26,315.42 ms,  2.33 GB
```

Ok, finally, I run it with `./app`. The result follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: Unsupported method of Unsafe
    at com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError.unsupportedFeature(VMError.java:86)
    at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.staticFieldOffset(Unsafe.java:230)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.staticFieldOffset(Unsafe.java:662)
    at Test.main(Test.java:9)
```

So it seems that in the native mode, it does not support `Unsafe.staticFieldOffset()` method.

Is there any way to make it work, or should it be addressed in the GraalVM code? This seems to obstruct the usage of Netty in native images, see https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/10051 as an example.

I'm using GraalVM 20.1:

```
openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 20.1.0 (build 11.0.7+10-jvmci-20.1-b02)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 20.1.0 (build 11.0.7+10-jvmci-20.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**PS** Configuration collection using an agent does not help. That is, when I add `-agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=target/config` to the `java` command to collect runtime data about reflection and stuff add then add `-H:ConfigurationFileDirectories=target/config` to the `native-image` command, the resulting native program behaves identically.

Comment: The issue is tracked here: https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/2694
It was recently closed, but even the nightly builds still reproduce the same behavior as before.